# How to do arithmetic on imported array in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and only a student so if this question is extremely trivial I apologize

I've imported a .csv file and indexed 2 columns using panda using the following:

```
data_AM = pd.read_csv(name_AM, header = None, names = None, usecols = [2,4])
```

I want to subtract column 4 from column 2 but when I use np.subtract I get an error telling me that it is a string.

When I attempt to convert the whole column into floats it only converts the column index header to a float. For example, if I use:

```
x = [float(i) for i in time_AM]
```

where time_AM is column 2, the output is [2.0]

If I do the same thing for column 4, the output is [4.0]

Here is what the output time_AM looks like:

```
             2
3            0
4   2.83237624
5   7.64838266
6      11.6987
7     15.60853
8   19.3890476
9   25.1548729
10    30.15414
11    33.55736
12  37.2666435
13    41.67488
14    45.19324
15   50.327446
16  54.7211761
17  61.7345772
18    65.96731
19    72.20469
20    76.48047
21    80.90832
22    84.74452
```

Any advice on how to do arithmetic with this? Basically I am trying to automate something that would be extremely simple in excel because I'm gonna have to do it a bunch of times.

Comment: You can set the datatype of each column when you read the array using the `dtype` argument. See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more detail

Comment: please post a sample CSV file and expected output / resulting data set (which would reproduce your problem)- this will help us to understand what is your problem and help you to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data_AM.iloc[:, 2].astype('float64').subtract(data_AM.iloc[:,4].astype('float64'))
```

[`.astype('float64')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) will convert the datatype of the column to float. And [`subtract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.subtract.html) is the function you are looking for. [`.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) is an indexer that indexes by position rather than label.

I understand that the learning curve can be quite steep, Pandas is quite feature rich and there are lots of things in it. But do take a look at [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) for help.